# SQL Insert row if not exsist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am VERY new to mySQL, please bear with me.

I have an array that is always growing, lets say for now it has 4 items in it. I need the sql to search the table and insert a new row for each item in the array, but only if its a new item (meaning it hasn't already been inserted). There are 5 columns in the table, and each item in the row needs to be a variable so i can pass dynamic data through.

I know this is way off but what i have now is something like this.

```
$array_count = array(1,2,3,4);
$var1 = 'value 1';
$var2 = 'value 2';
$var3 = 'value 3';
$var4 = 'value 4';
$var5 = 'value 5';
$sql = "INSERT INTO membership_levels VALUES ('".$var1."', '".$var2."', '".$var3."', '".$var4."', '".$var5."')";
```

Comment: MySQL I assume? (given PHP context)

Comment: @marc - my question is how do i write it!! @brad - ya its mySQL, sorry i didnt realize there were more

Comment: "hasn't already been inserted". Do you mean in the same column it's trying to be inserted into or do you need it to make sure the value isn't currently in any of the five columns?

Comment: @webbiedave - the 5 columns are `id` `name` ect (unique values that each of the items from the `array` contain). The array is a multileveled array. So if that info hasnt yet been inserted, it should be inserted as a new row. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Mysql - ON DUPLICATE KEY

If you database is MySql you can use like Brad Christie has wrote with the [Insert On Duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You will need to have a primary key on the 5 columns if you want inserting only if they are all the same value.

Your $sql will change to :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO membership_levels(a,b,c,d) VALUES VALUES ('".$var1."', '".$var2."', '".$var3."', '".$var4."', '".$var5."')
               ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=VALUES(a), b=VALUES(b), c = VALUES(c), d = VALUES (d);"
```

#### Mysql - Replace

You can also use the [Replace key word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). If the row exist, it will delete it for you and insert the new one.

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO membership_levels VALUES ('".$var1."', '".$var2."', '".$var3."', '".$var4."', '".$var5."')";
```

#### MsSql

If you database is MsSql (Sql server) it's 2 queries :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)"
```

The best way if SQL Server would be to use Stored Procedure.

Comment: It is mySQL. I forgot to mention that. The first example wont work because the array has easily over 100 items in it. I will try the second example, and the first column is the id column, which is primary. One question though, i understand that VALUES is inserting a new row, but what is the SET doing? im not sure what i should add in there...

Comment: Set is for Update. When you update you do not INSERT but you SET the value ;)

Comment: You updated your answer before i submitted. If i use the REPLACE, it will be replacing over 100 rows every time the page refreshes. I dont know much about mySQL, but is that going to make things slow?

Comment: No, it check the unique key you have put on your table. IF it exist, it just update the value, otherwise it INSERT. Pretty fast. I do it with table over 1 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax?

I would need the PK (Primary Key) to give you an exact query to run with...

*Assuming this is MySQL given PHP tag*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article which I believe may answer your question: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/

It shows several possible ways of writing a SQL query to overcome the lack of "IF NOT EXISTS" syntax. Note that if you were using SQL Server, you could write IF NOT EXISTS.

Comment: You should always provide a summary of the external answer here for posterity. What if the page you're linking to disappears in six months?

Comment: @webbiedave - Good point. I have modified my answer accordingly.